# Change all pages permalinks instead of hierarchical to have id of the page

Tags: permalinks, pages, url-rewriting

I would like to change the permalinks of all the pages of my site to have instead of http://example.com/page1/page2/page3 http://example.com/152 where 152 is the id of the page.
Could i use page_rewrite_rules? and how?
I tried to set the permalinks to default which gives me for the pages the permalink ?page_id=pageid I would like instead to have just the pageid the ?page_id= should be removed from the permalink how could i do it? (It is for pages)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:[image]

You need goto this page http://example.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php

Comment: but it only works for posts not for pages

Comment: ah, I see... well, I forgot about that. I don't have the solution right now